# Windows doesn't boot after un-checking automatic managing pagefiles

Tags: windows-10, pagefile

I was trying to partition my disk, and in order to do that I unchecked automatic managing of pagefile in advanced settings and put the radio on "No pagefile" and restarted my PC, now it doesn't boot, it logs con some kind of troubleshooting screen where I have access to a cmd and some useless options. Pagefile.sys doesn't seem to exist anymore in X:\ and even if I try to write in the command prompt:

`wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" set AutomaticManagedPagefile=true`

And reboot nothing changes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Generally if you untick "Auto pagefile" option you should create one yourself with a specific size. Can you run this command `wmic.exe pagefile list /format:list` ? ([from here](https://garvis.ca/2018/02/07/change-the-page-in-command-line/))

Comment: @Smock - It is not unheard of to disable the page file in order to defrag the system drive, otherwise within Windows, pagefile.sys cannot be moved.  The author's system should boot, it might be slow due to the page file not existing, but it should at least boot without a page file.

Comment: @Ramhound I know it's not unheard of (I've done it myself once or twice on machines with a large memory capacity - temporarily), just saying it's not advisable for general operation. Anyway - if they run that command they should see if their command to set one back up is working and we can move on from that issue (but yes - it should still boot). What would be really handy is a screenshot/photo of what happens on boot.